# Preencher dinamicamente os campos de acordo com CEP JSP Javascript

Tags: javascript, java, html, jsp

Quero que ao digitar meu cep e clicar no botão de busca, ele retorna os dados do logradouro,estado,bairro e uf mas ao clicar no botão de busca ele não está chamando a função que faz a busca dos dados de uma webService do correio.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

 $(document).ready(function(){
$("#buscar_cep").click(function(e){
    if($.trim($("#cep").val()) != ""){
        $.getScript("http://cep.republicavirtual.com.br/web_cep.php?
 formato=javascript&cep="+$("#cep").val(), function(){
            if(resultadoCEP["resultado"]){
                $("#rua").val(unescape(resultadoCEP["tipo_logradouro"])+": 
 "+unescape(resultadoCEP["logradouro"]));
                $("#bairro").val(unescape(resultadoCEP["bairro"]));
                $("#cidade").val(unescape(resultadoCEP["cidade"]));
                $("#estado").val(unescape(resultadoCEP["uf"]));
            }else{
                alert("Não foi possivel encontrar o endereço");
            }
        });             
    }
})
});
    </script>

      <form >
 <div class="row">
 <div class="col-6 col-md-4">
    Nome Completo:<input type="text" id="nome_passageiro2" name="nome"><br/>
 <br/>
 </div>


 <div class="col-6 col-md-4">

     CEP:<input type="text" id="cep" name="cep"><button type="button" id="buscar_cep"><i class="fa fa-search" action="" ></i></button> <br/><br/>
 </div>

 <div class="col-6 col-md-4">
    Celular:<input type="text" id="nr_celular" name="celular"><br/><br/>
 </div>

  <div class="col-6 col-md-4">
    CPF:<input type="text" id="cpf" name="cpf" ><br/><br/>
  </div>

  <div class="col-6 col-md-4">
    UF:<input type="text" id="uf" name="uf" ><br/><br/>
 </div>

 <div class="col-6 col-md-4">
    Cidade:<input type="text" id="cidade" name="uf"><br/><br/>
 </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-6 col-md-4">
    Rua:<input type="text" id="rua" name="endereco"><br/><br/>
 </div>

           <div class="col-6 col-md-4">
    Estado:<input type="text" id="estado" name="endereco"><br/><br/>
 </div>

         <div class="col-6 col-md-4">
    Bairro:<input type="text" id="bairro" name="endereco"><br/><br/>
 </div>
        <div class="col-6 col-md-4">
    Telefone:<input type="text" id="modelo" name="telefone"><br/><br/>
        </div>

        <div class="col-6 col-md-4">
    Login:<input type="text" id="login" name="login"><br/><br/>
        </div>

        <div class="col-6 col-md-4">
            Senha:<input type="password" id="senha" name="senha"><br/><br/>
        </div>

        <div class="col-6 col-md-4">
            Confirmar Senha:<input type="password" id="senha" name="confirma_senha"><br/><br/>
        </div>
        <div class="col-6 col-md-4">
     Data de Nascimento:<input type="text" id="nascimento_dt" name="nascimento"><br/><br/>
 </div>

            <div class="col-6 col-md-4">
    Estado Civil:  <label for="s1">Solteiro(a)</label>
        <input type="radio" id="ativo" name="status"  value="ativo"/>

        <label for="s2">Casado(a)</label>
        <input type="radio" id="inativo" name="status" value="inativo"/>
  <br/><br/>
            </div>





             <div class="col-6 col-md-4">
    Sexo:  <label for="s4">Masculino</label>
        <input type="radio" id="masc" name="sexo" value="masculino"/>

        <label for="s6">Feminino</label>
        <input type="radio" id="fem" name="sexo" value="feminino"/><br/>
    <br/>

        </div>
    </div>

        <button type="submit" onclick="validar()" >Cadastrar</button> 


    </form>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Da uma olhada nesse `webservice`:

https://viacep.com.br/exemplo/jquery/

Segue um exemplo de como utilizá-lo.

```js
$(function(){

  $("#buscar_cep").click(function(){
  
    //Nova variável "cep" somente com dígitos.
    var cep = $("#cep").val().replace(/\D/g, '');

    //Verifica se campo cep possui valor informado.
    if (cep != "") {

        //Expressão regular para validar o CEP.
        var validacep = /^[0-9]{8}$/;

        //Valida o formato do CEP.
        if(validacep.test(cep)) {

         //Consulta o webservice viacep.com.br/
        $.getJSON("//viacep.com.br/ws/"+ cep +"/json/?callback=?", function(dados) {

                if (!("erro" in dados)) {
                    //Atualiza os campos com os valores da consulta.
                    $("#rua").val(dados.logradouro);
                    $("#bairro").val(dados.bairro);
                    $("#cidade").val(dados.localidade);
                    $("#uf").val(dados.uf);
                } //end if.
                else {
                    //CEP pesquisado não foi encontrado.
                    console.log("CEP não encontrado.");
                }
            });
        } //end if.
        else {
            console.log("Formato de CEP inválido.");
        }
    } //end if.
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form >
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-6 col-md-4">
      Nome Completo:
      <input type="text" id="nome_passageiro2" name="nome">
      <br/><br/>
  </div>
 <div class="col-6 col-md-4">
  CEP:
  <input type="text" id="cep" name="cep">
  <button type="button" id="buscar_cep">
    buscar
    <i class="fa fa-search" action="" ></i>
  </button>
  <br/><br/>
 </div>
 <div class="col-6 col-md-4">
    Celular:<input type="text" id="nr_celular" name="celular"><br/><br/>
 </div>

  <div class="col-6 col-md-4">
    CPF:<input type="text" id="cpf" name="cpf" ><br/><br/>
  </div>

  <div class="col-6 col-md-4">
    UF:<input type="text" id="uf" name="uf" ><br/><br/>
 </div>

 <div class="col-6 col-md-4">
    Cidade:<input type="text" id="cidade" name="uf"><br/><br/>
 </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-6 col-md-4">
    Rua:<input type="text" id="rua" name="endereco"><br/><br/>
 </div>

           <div class="col-6 col-md-4">
    Estado:<input type="text" id="estado" name="endereco"><br/><br/>
 </div>

         <div class="col-6 col-md-4">
    Bairro:<input type="text" id="bairro" name="endereco"><br/><br/>
 </div>
        <div class="col-6 col-md-4">
    Telefone:<input type="text" id="modelo" name="telefone"><br/><br/>
        </div>

        <div class="col-6 col-md-4">
    Login:<input type="text" id="login" name="login"><br/><br/>
        </div>

        <div class="col-6 col-md-4">
            Senha:<input type="password" id="senha" name="senha"><br/><br/>
        </div>

        <div class="col-6 col-md-4">
            Confirmar Senha:<input type="password" id="senha" name="confirma_senha"><br/><br/>
        </div>
        <div class="col-6 col-md-4">
     Data de Nascimento:<input type="text" id="nascimento_dt" name="nascimento"><br/><br/>
 </div>

            <div class="col-6 col-md-4">
    Estado Civil:  <label for="s1">Solteiro(a)</label>
        <input type="radio" id="ativo" name="status"  value="ativo"/>

        <label for="s2">Casado(a)</label>
        <input type="radio" id="inativo" name="status" value="inativo"/>
  <br/><br/>
            </div>





             <div class="col-6 col-md-4">
    Sexo:  <label for="s4">Masculino</label>
        <input type="radio" id="masc" name="sexo" value="masculino"/>

        <label for="s6">Feminino</label>
        <input type="radio" id="fem" name="sexo" value="feminino"/><br/>
    <br/>

        </div>
    </div>

        <button type="submit" onclick="validar()" >Cadastrar</button> 


    </form>
```

Comment: funcionou perfeitamente Caique obrigado